# Show the closure of the intersection of two open set is whole space X

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Let X be a metric space and $U_1\subset X$ and $U_2\subset X$, such that $\overline{U_1}=\overline{U_2}=X$.

Now assume also $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open, and show that $\overline {U_1\cap U_2}=X$.

Comment: What did you try? Its your exercise, not ours. We may help you solve it, if you show some effort, though...

Answer (score 1):

Every $x\in X$ has a neighbourhood $N_i$ such that $N_i\cap U_i\neq\emptyset$, for $i=1, 2$. Now, what about $(N_1\cap N_2)\cap(U_1\cap U_2)=(N_1\cap U_1)\cap(N_2\cap U_2)$? Note that $N_i\cap U_i$ is a nbd of $x$, since $U_i$ is open, so $x\in (N_1\cap U_1),(N_2\cap U_2)$, and so $x\in(N_1\cap U_1)\cap(N_2\cap U_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $O$ be open and non-empty. Then $U_1 \cap O$ is open (intersection of two open sets) and non-empty ($U_1$ is dense). But then again (as $U_2$ is dense), $(U_1 \cap O) \cap U_2 = O \cap (U_1 \cap U_2)$ is non-empty and so $O$ intersects $U_1 \cap U_2$. As $O$ was arbitrary, this shows that the latter set is dense.

Note that we only need one of the dense sets to be open.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a topological space, $U_1,U_2$ open subsets  with $\overline{U_1}=\overline{U_2}=X$, whic means that the only open set disjoint from $U_1$ (or $U_2$) is the empty set.

Let $V$ be open with $(U_1\cap U_2)\cap V=\emptyset$. Then  $U_1\cap V$ is open and disjoint from $U_2$, hence empty. And $U_2\cap V$ is open and disjoint from $U_1$, hence empty.
Then 
$V\cap(U_1\cup U_2)=(V_1\cap U_1)\cup (V\cap U_2) $ is also empty, hence $V$ is also disjoint from $\overline{U_1\cup U_2}$ and even more so from $\overline{U_1}$. Hence $V=\emptyset$.
But if the only open set disjoint from $U_1\cap U_2$ is the empty set, then $\overline{U_1\cap U_2}=X$.